# Installing Graphlab create on Anaconda on Windows 10 (Python, Machine Learning)

Tags: python, anaconda, graphlab, turi

I'm following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/aXec_IqKA74) on youtube to install graphlab creat, but when I try to go to **https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html** and create an account on graphlab create and get a license to complete the installation I get this github page!

What is wrong? Is graphlab create no loger used?
What are the new steps I need to follow to install graphlab create?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question. it seems like graphlab is no longer used. try using `(venv) pip install -U turicreate` if you are using anaconda on windows 10

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).